# Unable to drop table in Firebird

Tags: firebird

I open a command prompt in `Ubuntu` and then log in to `Firebird`, like so:

```
$ isql-fb
SQL> connect "localhost:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/reestr.fdb" user 'SYSDBA' password 'root';
```

Then I list all tables in my database:

```
 > show tables;
   ARCHIVE_1_    ...
   ...
   ...
```

Finally, I want to drop one table. I try it this way:

```
> DROP TABLE ARCHIVE_1_;
........ absolutely no reaction, propmt is waiting for something
```

If I log in again and list tables, I see that the table is still there. So, what is wrong with all that?

**EDIT**

This is what `set;` command in isql prompt returns:

```
Print statistics:        OFF
Echo commands:           OFF
List format:             OFF
List Row Count:          OFF
Select rowcount limit:   0
Autocommit DDL:          ON
Access Plan:             OFF
Access Plan only:        OFF
Display BLOB type:       1
Column headings:         ON
Terminator:              ;
Time:                    OFF
Warnings:                ON
Bail on error:           OFF
```

Comment: Could you try a commit before the `DROP`, or configure a no wait transaction. It can make a difference.

Comment: I will check it now.

Comment: Doing commit before `DROP` works! But can you please elaborate a bit on how to configure no wait transactions? I wish I could run queries without copy and paste of `COMMIT` at each place.

Comment: Setting a no wait transaction might not help for this specific problem, but might make the failure immediate instead of hanging. The problem is that you can't drop a table if it is in use (or if the metadata is in use, for example by executing a `show tables`) by an active transaction (including your own). Setting transaction option is documented under [`SET TRANSACTION`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-set-trans.html)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have turned off autocommit of DDL statements (the default is on). To check use `set;` command in the isql, it'll list the current setup. If the autoddl is off then you can set it on again using `SET AUTODDL ON;` or just issue `commit;` after you'r DROP statement.

Comment: Hm. I checked it. The whole list of poperties is in an updated question.